# Cannot Get Boot2Docker Installed Mac OS X 10.10.2

Tags: macos, installation, boot2docker

I have tried installing docker/boot2docker on my mac and no matter what I do I cannot get it through the "up" process.

I tried installing via brew
- That did not work, so I uninstalled everything

I tried installing via the docker site (package that installs VirtualBox, Docker, Boot2Docker)
- again, when I try "up" it just hangs and will not finish.

This should not be an issue because I tried this install after reformatting my hard drive ...

I have tried all of the 'solutions' that have been suggested all over the web, from checking my etc/hosts file so that "127.0.0.1 localhost" is there to going into VirtualBox deleting the VM then running "init" again... all the way to uninstalling absolutely everything on my computer and trying a fresh install ...

When I do the docker command "up" it just hangs.  Not once have I made it to the end of this process. This is the line it hangs on and repeats over and over again:

---

.Connecting to tcp://localhost:2022 (attempt #0)2015/03/21 19:49:47 executing: /usr/bin/ssh ssh -o IdentitiesOnly=yes -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null -o LogLevel=quiet -p 2022 -i /Users/me/.ssh/id_boot2docker docker@localhost ip addr show dev eth1

---

Prior to reformatting my hard drive, I had this installed before without any issues.  I do not remember the version I had installed, but my guess is that it was not v1.5.0.

After trying for nearly 13 hours to get this to work, I am pretty much ready to throw in the towel and be done with it unless someone can tell me how to get it to work.

Comment: 1.7.1 is out, have you tried that?   Perhaps 1.5.0 was just broken.  I know 1.7.0 was.  1.7.1 works fine on 10.9 and 10.10 (I've tried several machines).

Comment: Also, did Console show anything?  Also, I've seen weird issues with the Mac Firewall.  Try turning it off.